# ImageView not taking full height available to it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have created a list-item `layout` for `ListView`.The `ListView` item has a `ImageView` which I want to take up full height matching parent but its not using the full height.Also I want Image to be vertically centered .My List-item `layout` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="15.0dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigationParent"
        android:layout_width="50.0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/blue" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navigationItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/navigation_item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nHeading"
        style="@style/listItemHeadingText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/navigationParent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nOverview"
        style="@style/listItemOverviewText"
        android:layout_below="@id/nHeading"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/navigationParent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The output I am getting is shown in below image :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my xml code and now it's working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="15.0dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/navigationItem"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nHeading"
            style="@style/listItemHeadingText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nOverview"
            style="@style/listItemOverviewText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigationItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_item" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigationItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_item" />
```

to

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigationItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_item" />
```

but it will stretch the image too much probably. Try using an image of appropriate dimensions

Comment: it's not working using your solution.The output is same as I have provided in screenshot.

Comment: Do you want to stretch the image or just center it?

Comment: just center the image and do not stretch

Comment: Try adding `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to your `LinearLayout` in your original code

Comment: But first of all it should use full height which is my main problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigationItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="refer**"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_item" />
```

** [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: I expected that your solution will work but no luck, It's still displaying the same result as posted in screenshot